# Nested attributes com rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para estudo, que vai permitir a criação de um usuário. Este usuário, por sua vez, terá um inventário, que possuirá vários itens.

A minha dúvida é como salvar todos estes recursos de uma vez quando acessar a action `new` de `UsersController`.

Estou utilizando o `cocoon`, e o erro que aparece é:

```
undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass
```

**Models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :inventory

  delegate :items, to: :inventory, prefix: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :inventory
end

class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inventory_items
  has_many :items, through: :inventory_items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :inventory_items, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class InventoryItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :inventory
end
```

**Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new.tap do |user|
      user.inventory = Inventory.new
      user.inventory_items.build
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params
      .require(:user)
      .permit(
        :name,
        :lat,
        :long,
        :age,
        inventory_attributes: [:id, inventory_items_attributes: [:quantity, :inventory_id, :item_id, :_destroy]]
      )
  end
end
```

**Formulário para cadastro de usuáro**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :lat %>
    <%= f.input :long %>
  </div>

  <h3>Items</h3>
  <div id="inventory_items">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :inventory do |inventory| %>
      <%= inventory.simple_fields_for :inventory_items do |f| %>
        <%= render 'item_fields', f: f %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Partial para os itens**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.collection_select :item_id, Item.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= f.input :quantity %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove item", f %>
</div>
```

**Observação:** O inventário não possui mais nenhum atributo além de seu `id` e o `user_id`.

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia!

Tente mudar isso:

```
<h3>Items</h3>
  <div id="inventory_items">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :inventory do |inventory| %>
      <%= inventory.simple_fields_for :inventory_items do |f| %>
        <%= render 'item_fields', f: f %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Para isso:

```
<h3>Items</h3>
  <div id="inventory_items">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :inventory do |inventory| %>
      <%= inventory.simple_fields_for :inventory_items do |item| %>
        <%= render 'item_fields', f: item %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Pode ser que esteja se perdendo nos f's pois estão referenciando coisas distintas.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer a seguinte alteração.

```
@user = User.new.tap
@user.build_inventory
@user.inventory.inventory_items.build
```

Esta outra pergunta me ajudou a esclarecer bastante o uso de build_ e .build. Recomendo dar uma olhada.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472982/using-build-with-a-has-one-association-in-rails